# possible different ways to get the kanto starters and ways to get fossils in x and y

Tags: pokemon-x-y

hi there I was wondering if you guys would happen to know the most effective ways to get the kanto starter pokemon because using friend safari seems kind of ineffective and slow.
also how would one obtain fossils aside from the original glittering cave ones thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Most effective' ways might be subjective. I do prefer the Friend Safari because of the guaranteed 31 IVs in at least 2 stats; which can't be easily obatined otherwise unless you search thoroughly.

Usually you can trade; friend, GTS, acquaintance and people sometimes put pokemon with 31 IVs in particular stats in GTS (you can identify them with their description, for example 31 HS usually means 31 IVs in HP and Speed).

You could say that this one's a lot faster, but it really depends on when you check GTS out. For instance, starters would be easily obtained early after the release, and I haven't been there lately but I think that the GTS activity might have died down a bit when compared to before.

For the fossils, again you can use the GTS if you don't have someone willing or able to trade you one. Another option though is to check out the Glittering Cave and Rock Smash boulders again and again (just exit the main cave and come back in to have the boulders appear again) though you might consider this as taking a long time. Took me a few days to be able to get at least one of each fossil (of course I didn't just look for fossils)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the Glittering Cave and grind for fossils in the big boulder room.